# code in asp validationExpression to vallidate an expression eneable us to Avoid any lettre (d) in the end of the Word

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i need a code in asp validationExpression  to vallidate an expression that can eneable us to Avoid the submit if ther is any lettre (d) in the end of the Word

exemples :

disable : GIAC1-IMME-D (BAD)

eneable : GIAC1-IMME (GOOD)

put it here :

```
     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5"  runat="server" ControlToValidate="date_Fin" 
Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid date"
 ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=""></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

tnks my clan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the ValidationExpression attribute of the RegularExpressionValidator control.  If that is the case you can use the regex below. It will match any string that contains anything except a newline character and doesn't end in a lower or uppercase d.

```
^.*[^Dd]$
```

Comment: this is it tnks my friend ... i have an another probléme i want to use it in a CreateUserWizard it doesn't work

Comment: The CreateUserWizard issue could be just a matter of making sure your ValidationGroup attributes have the same value everywhere.  These two SO links seem to address that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955280/server-side-validation-for-createuserwizard and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923492/regular-expression-validation-control-stops-working-when-embedded-in-a-createuse

Comment: tnks dudde .. that's it so all what i need it to write the validation groupe i use it and it works as well tnksssssss

Answer (score 0):

CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

RuleFor(x => x.Field).Trim().ToUpper()
.EndsWith("D")
.WithMessage("No Ds please");

Comment: tnks dudde .... but i need to put it here :
                          &nbsp;<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" 
                                    runat="server" ControlToValidate="date_Fin" Display="Dynamic" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Invalid date" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=""></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: Oh so you are trying to do it through regular expression. Hopefully putting in what ryanulit suggested in the ValidationExpression will work.